# Prevent trigger from updating all rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

I'm new to databases in fact i'm still learning by self-taught right now, what i'm missing from this trigger query?

```sql
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER  scores_insert
AFTER INSERT ON scoreList
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.score > 75 THEN
    UPDATE student SET `status` = 'pass' WHERE (#condition)
ELSE
    UPDATE student SET `status` = 'fail' WHERE (#condition)
END IF;

END; //
```

i've tried using subquery to #condition but its stll updating all the rows

Comment: Not enough detail.  Your UPDATE needs to use the student_id of the NEW row to restrict which student row is touched.  It's also a little odd to touch the student table to indicate pass/fail for one course.  Then again, you didn't provide enough detail about the tables and requirement.  Add that detail to the question.

Comment: Debugging suggestion - When testing triggers I usually write enough information to a table designed by me for this purpose inserting at each key point. After I'm happy I edit the table out of the trigger.

Comment: Provide the data enough for to reproduce your problem (CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO for both tables).